# Bootstrap 3 - Glyphicon and Font Awesome together? possible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just a quick question, the Bootstrap 3 I had packaged had the Glyphicon LESS file commented out because it had FA (Font Awesome) packaged in, is there any reason why I can't uncomment out the Glyphicons or are you not supposed to have them at the same time in Bootstrap?

thanks

Comment: Why not just do that and see what will happen? Also you can include FA, it has different styles (`fa fa-whatever`), and use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use both within my projects without any issues.
they use different prefixes also with fa- for font awesome and glyphicon- for the glyphicons.

I guess the only down side is the extra loading of additional fonts etc.

Hope that helps.